# Loading a file gives a "Class not found" error

Tags: clojure

Basically I'm trying to load a file with functions, to a file thats gonna do the test, both of which are in the same folder on Desktop. However, this line gives an error.

```
(load-file “file2.clj”)

clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: “file2.clj”, compiling:(C:\..\...\...\...\testfile.clj:1:1)
```

Comment: possibly the path to file is wrong. Check it like this: `(.getAbsolutePath (clojure.java.io/file "."))` . I bet you would have to `(load-file "src/file2.clj")` (well it depends on your project structure)

Comment: @leetwinski  I only have 2 files, file2 and testfile in the folder. I have testfile opened and I'm trying  to load file2 from there.

Comment: just try to print out the absolute path of 'file2.clj', to be sure

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have typographic quotes there: `(load-file “file2.clj”)`.  Replace them by ASCII quotes: `(load-file "file2.clj")`.

Comment: I still get the error
---------
      java.io.FileNotFoundException: file2.clj (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Then most likely your working directory is not what you think it is.  It is in general the directory you invoked `java` from.  Seeing that you used the name “Desktop” as some kind of place on your computer, I guess that you are using some point-and-click interacton in Windows to start it—I have no idea how to change that, but you should be able to see it in the `user.dir` system property.

Comment: i fixed the problem by running clojure from cmd line, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to use relative or absolute path to load the file. relative path is recommended... src/{app-name}/filename